# Can't reinizialize ngrx's state's feature

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx

I'm working with ngrx and this is my initialState:

```js
export interface Bonus110State {
  agent: Agent;
  isEdited: boolean;
  isResetted: boolean;
  steps: Step[];
  response: ResponseReport;
  customer: any | null;
  address: Address | null;
  error: boolean | null;
}

export const initialState: Bonus110State = {
  agent: {
    name: null,
    eta: null
  },
  customer: null,
  response: {
    responseCode: null,
    responseMessage: null
  },
  address: {
    isset: false,
    id: null,
    street: null,
    streetNumber: null,
    city: null,
    cap: null,
    province: null,
    firstname: null,
    lastname: null,
    vat: null,
    taxid: null,
    business_name: null
  },
  isEdited: false,
  isResetted: false,
  steps: [...environment.initialStateMap],
  error: null
};
```

i need reinitialize the state feature. This is my reducer's case:

```js
case Bonus110ActionTypes.CLEAR_BONUS110_STATE: {
      const newState = Object.assign({}, initialState);
      newState.isResetted = true;
      console.log('NEWSTATE', newState);
      
      return newState;
```

I'm expecting that this reducer, clean my feature state, returning it equal to the initialState.

But the state dosen't change. If i log the initialState, it is equal to the actual state

The only way I can reset it is doing this before the reducer inizialization

```
const initialStateCloned: Bonus110State = _cloneDeep(initialState);
```

and then

```js
case Bonus110ActionTypes.CLEAR_BONUS110_STATE: {
      const newState = Object.assign({}, initialStateCloned);
      newState.isResetted = true;
      console.log('NEWSTATE', newState);
      
      return newState;
```

I'm using the metareducer to clear all the state, and it is working well. but in this case i need to clear only this slice of state. i'm struggling on this from a while.

Comment: What to do you mean initialState is not empty?

Comment: That means that somewhere in the code you are overwriting you initial state. And just a minor grammatical error, it's spelled equal.

Comment: Yes my english is wrost of my js XD

Comment: Ok so i did a mistake somewhere

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `Object.assign` with spread operator. I believe it is recommended if you want to enforce immutability. Which in NgRx you do.

```
case Bonus110ActionTypes.CLEAR_BONUS110_STATE: {
  const newState = {
    ...initialState,
    isResetted: true
  }
  //console.log('NEW STATE:', newstate);
  return newState.
}
```

But as I have mentioned in the comment, it looks like you already replaced your initial state somewhere so check all you reducers.

Comment: I tried, bit the initialState is even full. I think i have problem with the metareducer that overwrite the state. I'm checking right now. Thanks for your answer